# How to achieve a large tibble divided by a column within using transmute_if / transmute_at

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I have a tibble, say:

```
> library(tibble)
> as_tibble(iris)
# A tibble: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <fctr>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
 8          5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
# ... with 140 more rows
```

I could I divide every column by say `Petal.width` using transmute_if or transmute_at?

Something like

```
> iris[,-c(5)]/iris[,4]
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1      25.500000   17.500000     7.000000           1
2      24.500000   15.000000     7.000000           1
3      23.500000   16.000000     6.500000           1
4      23.000000   15.500000     7.500000           1
5      25.000000   18.000000     7.000000           1
6      13.500000    9.750000     4.250000           1
7      15.333333   11.333333     4.666667           1
8      25.000000   17.000000     7.500000           1
9      22.000000   14.500000     7.000000           1
10     49.000000   31.000000    15.000000           1
11     27.000000   18.500000     7.500000           1
```

But without knowing the exact variable names, only the ending of `.Length` and `.Width`

Thanks,

Comment: There is an `ends_with` function in `dplyr`

Comment: I tried the transmute_if(ends_with())` combo. It doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use either of them.  The difference is suppose, we want to do the transformation only for `numeric` columns, then `transmute_if` would be more appropriate by avoiding the indexing or by column names

```
iris %>% 
   as_tibble %>% 
   transmute_if(is.numeric, funs(./iris$Petal.Width))
```

If we already know the column names or index, `transmute_at` can be used

```
iris %>%
   as_tibble %>%
   transmute_at(1:4, funs(./iris$Petal.Width))
```

If it is specific to particular set of columns, say those having 'Width" as suffix part in column names

```
iris %>%
    as_tibble %>% 
    transmute_at(vars(ends_with("Width")), funs(./iris$Petal.Width))
```

If the intention is to keep other columns as well, use `mutate_at`

```
iris %>%
    as_tibble %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with("Width")), funs(./iris$Petal.Width))
```

Comment: There are other numeric columns I would like to exclude. Could transmute_if *pick* the variable names?

Comment: @axiom If that is the case, go with `transmute_at` by either passing an index or the actual column names or if there are patterns use `matches` etc

Comment: `iris %>%
    as_tibble %>% 
    transmute_at(vars(ends_with("Width")), funs(./iris$Petal.Width))` works great. Thanks!  One more question. How could I preserve the columns that didn't go through the division? Say the `Species` column.

Comment: @axiom In that case, just use `mutate_at` instead of `transmute_at` as `transmute` only gives the output of the columns that you passed

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks a lot